# Hive External Table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to import data from Oracle to Hive using sqoop.
I used the command below once, now I want to overwrite the existing data with new data (Daily Action).
I ran this command again.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@UK01WRS6014:2184:WWSYOIT1 
--username HIVE --password hive --table OIDS.ALLOCATION_SESSION_DIMN 
--hive-overwrite --hive-database OI_DB --hive-table ALLOCATION_SESSION_DIMN
```

But I am getting an error File already exists:

```
14/10/14 07:43:59 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: 
PriviledgedActionException as:axchat 
(auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: 
Output directory 
hdfs://uslibeiadg004.aceina.com:8020/user/axchat/OIDS.ALLOCATION_SESSION_DIMN 
already exists
```

The tables that I created in hive were all external tables.
Like mapreduce, do we have to delete that file everytime we execute the same command ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete from an `EXTERNAL` table you only delete objects in the Hive metastore: you don't delete the files over which that table is superimposed. A non-external table belongs soley to Hive and, when deleted, will result in metastore- ***AND*** HDFS-data being removed.

So you can either try deleting the HDFS data explicitly, or define the table as being internal to hive.

Comment: in my case, since i have created external table structure in hive, and then sqoop-importing data into those external tables using --hive-overwrite. I dont know why am i getting the FileAlreadyExists error. it should not give the error since im overwriting it. am i correct ?

Comment: You have hive overwrite, but not hdfs overwrite.

Comment: @devek - if i drop those external tables, recreate managed tables, n import data, it will load fine. again if i import data using --hive-overwrite, i should not get FileAlreadyExists error. am i right ?

Comment: @aiman: if you have external tables, then hive does *not* have the authority to delete the underlying tables in hdfs, only the table defintion in the metastore. Only when the tables are internal to hive can you do that.

Comment: okk...means i have to create managed tables to use --hive-overwrite.  thanks davek :D ...that shud help